# java spring framework 4 for building social networking web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am new to Java Spring 4. I have to develop a social networking web application in java Spring 4. Is there any sample application (Like NopCommerce in Asp.Net) covering all the advanced web development features like MVVM Model,  Authentication, Authorization, Scaffolding, Concurrency, Web services implementation. I have to handle huge traffic on that network from millions of visits daily. Is Spring 4 suitable for high load web applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at sample spring projects [here](https://github.com/spring-projects). And yes Spring is perfect for writing scalable java enterprise applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose all Spring feaches you need for your applications. for example Spring boot + Spring MVC + Spring Security + Spring (Hibernate/EBean/...) + what ever you need. And there are docs and samples for every type of Spring tech.